# How can I access the ProcessModule.Events property?

Tags: c#, process

ProcessModule.Events - from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodule_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Here is my code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] procs = 
          System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(TARGET_BASE);
if (procs.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in procs)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule pm = p.MainModule;
        System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList ehl = pm.Events;
    }
}
```

The compiler complains about `ehl = pm.Events`, that:

'System.ComponentModel.Component.Events' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Note that I don't get the error accessing other properties of the ProcessModule. The compiler is complaining that the get accessor of .Events is inaccessible because of its protection level.

Comment: That ProcessModule inherits *Events* from the Component class is a pretty bizarre .NET 1.0 quirk.  It most certainly does *not* do what you hope it does, there is no way to get to events in another process.  That compile error was certainly meant to keep you from making this mistake.

Comment: That would explain why Intellisense refused to show me the Events property :-).  Hans, you should probably just make your response an Answer... the answer being "You can't do that, no matter what MSDN says".

Comment: I like happy answers, like most SO users do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) clearly states this property is `protected`.  That means that only classes derived from the object's type can access this property on it.

This lines up with most event implementations in .NET.  Public users are generally limited to adding and removing handlers, without the ability to view, replace, or clear the entire list of handlers.  Despite the fact this is a property, not a true event, it seems to be following the same approach of limited access.